# Instant logout message received when trying to connect on Quickfix

Tags: python, python-3.5, quickfix, quickfixj, quickfixn

I have been trying to deal with this problem for sometime now and I believe it may have something to do with MsgSeqNum being out of sync between the client and the server but as it had began as a random thing and now makes it impossible to connect I am not so sure anymore.

Sometimes after activating the flag to reset MsgSeqNum client-side it will return a message that the server was expecting a higher MsgSeqNum and received "1" (as I had reset mine) but even if I repeatedly try to connect to increase my client-side MsgSeqNum to match the server's I arrive at this same error I show below in my log.

In the log messages like "onCreate" are just debugging messages I added to track what methods do end up getting executed.

If anyone can offer insight into this issue and anything new to try I'd appreciate it and thank you for reading!

Note: I cannot reset the server's MsgSeqNum because you can only send that flag after logging in, which I never get the chance to do.

```
onCreate
<20180619-19:51:30.000000000, FIX.4.4:SENDER->TARGET, event>
  (Created session)
<20180619-19:51:30.000000000, FIX.4.4:SENDER->TARGET, event>
  (Connecting to BROKERADDRESS on port 8101 (Source :0))
toAdmin
<20180619-19:51:30.000000000, FIX.4.4:SENDER->TARGET, outgoing>
  (8=FIX.4.4 9=112 35=A 34=52 49=SENDER 52=20180619-19:51:30.000 56=TARGET 554=PASSWORD 98=0 108=5 10=220 )
<20180619-19:51:30.000000000, FIX.4.4:SENDER->TARGET, event>
  (Initiated logon request)
<20180619-19:51:31.000000000, FIX.4.4:SENDER->TARGET, incoming>
  (8=FIX.4.4 9=77 35=5 34=40 49=TARGET 52=20180619-19:51:31.691 56=SENDER 10=228 )
fromAdmin
<20180619-19:51:31.000000000, FIX.4.4:SENDER->TARGET, event>
  (Received logout request)
toAdmin
<20180619-19:51:31.000000000, FIX.4.4:SENDER->TARGET, outgoing>
  (8=FIX.4.4 9=77 35=5 34=53 49=SENDER 52=20180619-19:51:31.000 56=TARGET 10=216 )
<20180619-19:51:31.000000000, FIX.4.4:SENDER->TARGET, event>
  (Sending logout response)
<20180619-19:51:31.000000000, FIX.4.4:SENDER->TARGET, event>
  (Disconnecting)
onLogout
toAdmin
```

Comment: What are all those tags for? Are you using QuickFix/J and QuickFIX C# in a Python script somehow?

Comment: @abarnert So of course that's the most important thing I know, but people who use QuickFix for Java and C# can offer input on this because it is Quickfix issue as more than it is a Python problem. I am running the Python version of Quickfix. Do you have any help to offer?

Comment: Really down-voting this post? What more do you want from me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is expecting a higher sequence number. To fix this problem, you can send ResetSeqNumFlag (Tag = 141) as Y as after this your server should also reset its sequence number.

You can use Quickfixj config ResetOnLogon as Y in your application which will automatically do this on logon.

Please refer https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.1/usage/configuration.html

Comment: Right but in my post "Note: I cannot reset the server's MsgSeqNum because you can only send that flag after logging in, which I never get the chance to do." the main problem is that you have to log in to be able to send that flag and the server is not letting me even log in before it boots me out of it.

Comment: I'm starting to think I'm making a mistake and confusing the method onLogon with the FIX message of "Logon". Do you think this is correct?

Comment: Whenever your application connects to server, it will sent a Logon message(35=A) so when you set ResetOnLogon as Y in your application then it will automatically sent 141=Y with 35=A message. So a successful logon is not required to send that flag